# find amazon categories using python

Tags: python, java, json

I would like to get the categories of the `amazon` ,I am planning to scrap not to use API.
I have scrapped the `http://www.amazon.com`.I have scraped all the categories and sub-categories under `Shop By Department` drop down .I have created a web service to do this The code is here

```
@route('/hello')
def hello():
    text=list();
    link=list();
    req = urllib2.Request("http://www.amazon.com",
                  headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
    html=urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    last_page = soup.find('div', id="nav_subcats")
    for elm in last_page.findAll('a'):
        texts = elm.text
        links = elm.get('href')
        links = links.partition("&node=")[2]
        text.append(texts)
        link.append(links)
    alltext=list();
    for i,j in zip(text,link):
        alltext.append({"name":i,"id":j})
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    print(alltext)
    return dumps(alltext)
run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

I am passing the category name and category id as a JSON object to one of my members to pass it to the API to get the product listing for each category

It is written in JAVA.Here is the code

```
for (int pageno = 1; pageno <= 10; pageno++) {
            String page = String.valueOf(pageno);
            String category_string = selectedOption.get("category_name").toString();
            String category_id = selectedOption.get("category_id").toString();
            final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>(3);
            params.put(AmazonClient.Op.PARAM_OPERATION, "ItemSearch");
            params.put("SearchIndex", category_string);
            params.put("BrowseNodeId", category_id);
            params.put("Keywords", category_string);
            params.put("ItemPage", page);
            System.out.println(client.documentToString(client.getXml(params)));
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            Document doc = null;
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputStream is = client.getInputStream(params);

            doc = db.parse(is);
            NodeList itemList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Items");
```

But i am getting this error when i pass the category id as the BrowseNodeId and category name as keyword and search index.

```
 For example
     Search Index and Keyword -Amazon Instant Video
     BrowseNodeId-2858778011

The value you specified for SearchIndex is invalid. Valid values include [ 'All','Apparel',...................................reless','WirelessAccessories' ].
```

I would like to know from which amazon url i will get all the categories and its browse nodes

Thank you

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/gp/site-directory/ref=sa_menu_top_fullstore ?

Comment: @mhawke this is the same list that i i got when i have scrapped `Shop By Department` drop down

Comment: How are you passing your scraped category name and category id? Have you any code to show?

Comment: @mhawke Here is the code http://pastebin.com/HNrQ27yU please have look at the description at the top of the code too

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra please edit the question to include a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I have never looked at Amazon's API before, so this is just a guess but, based on the error message it would seem that "Amazon Instant Video" is not a valid search index. Just because it is there in the drop-down list, doesn't necessarily mean that it is a valid search index.

Here's a list of search indices for US: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/USSearchIndexParamForItemsearch.html . I don't know how up to date it is, but "Amazon Instant Video" does not appear on the list. The error message does include a list of valid search index values, and these do appear to correspond to the above list.

For other locales look here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/APPNDX_SearchIndexParamForItemsearch.html

I don't think that this is a coding problem per se.

You might like to take a look at [python-amazon-product-api](http://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). The API might be useful to you, and the documentation might give you some ideas.